# Appending np.arrays to a blank array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to save the results from a loop in a np.array.

```
    import numpy as np
    p=np.array([])
    points= np.array([[3,0,0],[-1,0,0]])

    for i in points:
       for j in points:
          if j[0]!=0:
             n=i+j
       p= np.append(p,n)
```

However the resulting array is a 1D array of 6 members.

```
    [2.  0.  0. -2.  0.  0.]
```

Instead I am looking for, but have been unable to produce:

```
    [[2,0,0],[-2,0,0]]
```

Is there any way to get the result above?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  There may be a better way to accomplish it.  Otherwise try ```p.reshape(points.shape)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to turn `p` into a list, and convert it into a NumPy array right at the end:

```
p = []
for i in points:
   ...
   p.append(n)
p = np.array(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is vertically stacking your results:

```
import numpy as np
p=np.empty((0,3))
points= np.array([[3,0,0],[-1,0,0]])

for i in points:
  for j in points:
    if j[0]!=0:
      n=i+j
  p= np.vstack((p,n))
print p
```

which gives:

```
[[ 2.  0.  0.]
 [-2.  0.  0.]]
```

Although you could also reshape your result afterwards:

```
import numpy as np
p=np.array([])
points= np.array([[3,0,0],[-1,0,0]])

for i in points:
  for j in points:
    if j[0]!=0:
      n=i+j
  p= np.append(p,n)
p=np.reshape(p,(-1,3))
print p
```

Which gives the same result
.

I must warn you, hovever, that your code fails if `j[0]!=0` as that would make `n` undefined...

[`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)
[`np.empty`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html)
[`np.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)